# How can I avoid this warning with boost:gil:png_write_view on x64

Tags: c++, boost, boost-gil

The following code issues  a warning:

```
boost::gil::rgb8_image_t img(10, 10);
boost::gil::png_write_view("TenByTen.png", view(img));
```

when compiled with VS 2010 under 64 bit. It says:

```
\boost\gil\extension\io\png_io_private.hpp(341): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from '__int64' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of data
\boost\gil\extension\io\png_io.hpp(202) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::gil::detail::png_writer::apply<View>(const View &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              View=boost::gil::image_view<boost::gil::rgb8_loc_t>
          ]
          main.cpp(20) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::gil::png_write_view<boost::gil::image_view<Loc>>(const char *,const View &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              Loc=boost::gil::rgb8_loc_t,
              View=boost::gil::image_view<boost::gil::rgb8_loc_t>
          ]
```

It seems quite obvious that in apply() the call to png_set_IHDR() should give a png_uint_32, but view.width() seems to be a signed __int64 (maybe a ptrdiff_t).

Does anybody know what i could do about it?
I guess that boost:gil is meant to work under 64 bits.

I use boost 1_50.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the specific issue is known from (at least) Boost v1.35 (e.g. http://objectmix.com/c/733997-how-use-graphics.html#post2586573).

Checking [Boost trac database](http://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/search?ticket=on) I see similar tickets for other modules but nothing for GIL.
Probably the best thing is open a new ticket.

Meanwhile, since it doesn't seem "catastrophic", you could wrap the `#include`(s) in this way:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#  pragma warning(push)
#  pragma warning(disable: 4244)  // Perhaps also 4100, 4127, 4512
// GIL headers
#  pragma warning(pop)
#endif
```

<sup>See also [How to: Enable and Disable Code Analysis for Specific C/C++ Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyhb0b82%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)</sup>

(with clang/gcc you have the `-isystem` switch, but I don't think Visual Studio lets you differentiate between application/header files)